# How to have routing and services in Polymer similar to Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, routes, polymer

In angular we are used to DI, services, routing and the like. I am wanting to hear from people who have projects that have transitioned to polymer from angular and what they found to be correct way to approach and accomplish similar feats in Polymer. I've found the easiest comparison to be made with the directives and custom polymer elements but from there things diverge.

How do we go about sharing some sort of "service" in a polymer app and create some sort of DI container where we can use to mock dependencies? Also would like to know how you accomplished (routing/nested routing) where before you could have used the ng-Router or UI-Router.

Comment: @see http://www.binpress.com/blog/2014/06/26/polymer-vs-angular/

Comment: Is there any reference available for this?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get going with routing https://github.com/erikringsmuth/polymer-router-demos.

When you use custom elements your APIs are HTML attributes. For now you have to test in the browser with Jasmine or QUnit since Node and PhantomJS don't support custom elements yet. You test by creating an instance of the element, calling a public function on it, and asserting the result.

HTML Imports are loosely equivalent to DI. I haven't seen any mocking libraries for HTML imports yet.

Services will be an interesting topic going forward. Right now you either include business logic in the custom element or have some external script calling public APIs on your custom elements and binding everything together.